# volatile array and multithreaded sorting

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, volatile

I'm considering implementations of multi-threaded sorting with use of one volatile array. Let's say I have an array of length N, and M threads that will sort sub-ranges of the array. These sub-ranges are disjoint. Then, in the main thread I will merge partially sorted array.

Example code:

```
final int N = ....
volatile MyClass[] array = new MyClass[N];
//... fill array with values

void sort(){
    MyThread[] workers = new MyThread[M];
    int len = N/M; //length of the sub-range
    for(int i=0;i<M;++i){
        workers[i] = new MyThread(i*len, (i+1)*len);
        workers[i].start();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<M;++i)workers.join();

    //now synchronization in memory using "happens before"
    //will it work?
    array = array;

    //...merge sorted sub-ranges into one sorted array
}

private class MyThread extends Thread{

final int from;
final int to;

public MyThread(int from, int to){ ..... }

public void run(){
    //...something like: quicksort(array, from, to);
    //...without synchronization, ranges <from, to> are exclusive
}
```

I don't need synchronization in memory while running threads because the array sub-ranges are disjoint. I want to do the synchronization once after finished threads. Will the updated version of the array (seen in the main thread) contain all the changes made in the working threads?

If this solution is valid, is it effective for large tables?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

I ran the tests. I received correct results regardless of the use of volatile keyword. But the time of execution is a few times (about M-times) longer for a volatile array.

Comment: How large are N and M going to be? How many threads can your target system run natively? It's likely that the overhead of context switching between threads will consume much of the speedup of multi-threading the sorting phase. You'll be left with a lot of complicated code and (maybe) a small performance gain.

Comment: N is about 10^6 and M is the number of processor cores

Comment: Sorting a million elements with plain `Collections.sort()` takes on average about 400ms for Integers, 650ms for hex Strings of those Integers on my machine. Unless `MyClass` has a super complex comparison logic, you're looking at a few seconds, as in <<5s. How fast to do you need this to be?

Comment: I wrote about sorting for simplicity. Working threads also perform other operations before sorting, and the whole process is repeated iteratively (my code is an implementation of genetic algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some thoughts:

There is no such thing as a volatile array.  Only fields can be volatile.  You have declared a volatile field named "array", and initialized it with a reference to an array object.

It looks like you are expecting the statement, `array = array` to act as a full memory barrier.  I don't know if it will or if it won't, or if the answer depends on what compiler, what JVM and, what operating system you use.  Maybe somebody more expert than I can answer.

I don't like it for two reasons though:  One is, it looks like a no-op.  It's an invitation for some other programmer who doesn't understand what you're trying to do to come along and "clean up" the code by deleting it.  A tricky statement like that should be wrapped in a function with a name that explains the trick.

Two is, the function of that statement has nothing to do with the array that the field references.  It would be better to use a volatile int field or a volatile somethingelse field that *obviously* has no connection to the array, thereby calling attention to the fact that what matters is something other than the value of the field.

---

Update:  According to Brian Goetz, that one statement won't do what you want.  What you need is for each worker thread to update the volatile field after finishing its work, and then you need the master thread to read the volatile field before it tries to look at the worker's results.

On the other hand...   Do you need the barrier at all?  Isn't it enough that the worker threads all terminated and the master join()ed them?  Again, maybe somebody more expert than myself can answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, the table doesn't need to be volatile, I think I  can use volatile 'flag' field. I'm not sure if the barrier is necessary here. Please read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks very messy and as suggested, probably won't work as expected.

If you use Java8 then perhaps the parallel sort is for you. Otherwise --

Sorting a single array in place, in parallel is a horror show. Sorting in parallel is rather simple if you create a new array of sorted elements.

Create objects of the the sub-array (you'll need to do this eventually). Pass each object to a thread. Let the threads sort their objects in parallel. When all sorts are done, merge the sorted objects into a new array.

That means there is more memory required, but its rather easy and you don't need to worry about volatile or synchronization.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I consider dividing my array into sub-arrays. Do I need the volatile barrier, then?

Comment: No. You're not accessing any fields concurrently.